# Why am I getting getString error? And how to resolve?

Tags: android, fragmentpageradapter, getstring

I am testing out the FragmentPagerAdapter and I had it all in a single class before. And everything worked, but once I separated SectionsPagerAdapter class, the getString doesn't work under the getPageTitle function.

I know getPageTitle is part of the PagerAdapter class, but I want to know what the best way to have that function included in this class. Do I need to extend the class?

**SectionsPageAdapter class**

```
import java.util.Locale;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

// A FragmentPagerAdapter that returns a fragment corresponding to one of the sections/tabs/pages. 
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override  
public Fragment getItem(int position) {  
    // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.  
    // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class  
    // below) with the page number as its lone argument.  
    Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();  
    Bundle args = new Bundle();  
    args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);  
    fragment.setArguments(args);  
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {  
    Locale l = Locale.getDefault();  
    switch (position) {  
    case 0:  
        return getString(R.string.myFriendsTab).toUpperCase(l);  
    case 1:
        return getString(R.string.myDealsTab).toUpperCase(l);  
    case 2:
        return getString(R.string.featuredDealsTab).toUpperCase(l);
    case 3:
        return getString(R.string.browseCategoriesTab).toUpperCase(l);  
    case 4:
        return getString(R.string.localDealsTab).toUpperCase(l);  
    }  
    return null;  
}

@Override  
public int getCount() {  
     // Show 5 total pages.  
     return 5;  
}
}
```

**MainActivity class**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    // Fragment PagerAdapter keeps every loaded fragment in memory. 
    // If too memory intensive, switch to FragmentStatePagerAdapter.
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    ViewPager mViewPager; // ViewPager that will host section contents.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Creates the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the primary sections.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "doesn't work"?

Comment: I am getting a red squiggly under the getString and it says method getString(int) is undefined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getString(int)` only works for Classes that have access to a `Context` - `Fragments`, `Activities`, etc.

Given that this an `Adapter` class, it won't have direct access to a `Context`, so you should probably pass one in with the constructor.

```
private Context mContext = null;

public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
    super(fm);
    mContext = context;
}
```

and then use the member field to access `getString(int)`

```
return mContext.getString(R.string.myFriendsTab).toUpperCase(1);
```

Comment: This solved the problem in the SectionsPagerAdapter class, but it crashes my program now. I added the MainActivity class code above, I just passed in "null" when I instantiated the class. Was I wrong to do so?

Comment: why would you pass in null? of course its going to crash then

Comment: I changed it to getBaseContext() and it works now. Sorry I'm relatively new to programming so I'm still in the trial and error phase. Thanks for the help!

Comment: you could also pass in your MainActivity, all Activity classes implement Context. glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

as [panini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1150776/panini) said, **getString** method need to be called on **Context**, follow these steps :

- Step 1 : in the adapter class, create a field to store the Context on it.

  ```
  private Context mContext
  ```
- Step 2 : in the adapter class, adjust the **constructor** to pass the Context as the first parameter.

  ```
       public SectionsPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
          super(fm);
          mContext = context;
      }
  ```
- Step 3 : in the adapter class, and inside the ***getPageTitle*** method, call the **getString** on the Context field **mContext**,

  ```
  @Override
  public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {  
  Locale l = Locale.getDefault();  
   switch (position) {  
    case 0:  
      return mContext.getString(R.string.myFriendsTab).toUpperCase(l);  
    case 1:
      return mContext.getString(R.string.myDealsTab).toUpperCase(l);  
    case 2:
      return mContext.getString(R.string.featuredDealsTab).toUpperCase(l);
    case 3:
      return mContext.getString(R.string.browseCategoriesTab).toUpperCase(l);  
    case 4:
      return mContext.getString(R.string.localDealsTab).toUpperCase(l);  
   }  
     return null;  
  }
  ```
- Step 4 : wherever you used the adapter adjust it to include the Context parameter as we defined in the constructor.

in **MainActivity** class, adjust the constructor to be like this :

```
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
```